# Does creating new logger for module still use the root logger name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I am looking at this article: https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

The paragraph:

> The root of the hierarchy of loggers is called the root logger. That’s
>   the logger used by the functions debug(), info(), warning(), error()
>   and critical(), which just call the same-named method of the root
>   logger. The functions and the methods have the same signatures. The
>   root logger’s name is printed as ‘root’ in the logged output.

I am confused because once you create a logger using `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and use logger.info/debug/etc., the name of the module should be printed and not root. Why does the paragraph say: "...which just call the same-named method of the root logger"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording is important.

> [...] That’s the logger used by the **functions** debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical(), which just call the same-named method of the root logger. [...]

The paragraph refers to the module-level utility functions [`debug()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2086), [`info()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2076), [`warning()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2061),  [`error()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2043) and [`critical()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2031). All of them, in fact, operate on the root logger, e.g.:

```
def debug(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Log a message with severity 'DEBUG' on the root logger. If the logger has
    no handlers, call basicConfig() to add a console handler with a pre-defined
    format.
    """
    if len(root.handlers) == 0:
        basicConfig()
    root.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

These module-level functions can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#module-level-functions).

Of course, when creating your own logger via `logging.getLogger(__name__)` and calling the respective methods on that instance, you operate on your logger, not the root (primarily, there's still propagation, unless explicitly disabled).

Edit:
I just realized that this question, and your previous one, have already been answered by [George's excellent, in-depth reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57799639/4134674) to your slightly earlier question. I highly recommend to read it thoroughly.